# The code is giving error at MultiSheetsPdf

Tags: c#, autocad, export-to-pdf, autocad-plugin

This is my code which create PDF of a dwg file but it gives me error near MultiSheetPdf. Please give me the solution for same.
I thought that linking is the problem but I am not able to identify please suggest me the solution.

```
  namespace Plottings
  {
  public class MultiSheetsPdf
  {
    private string dwgFile, pdfFile, dsdFile, outputDir;
    private int sheetNum;
    private IEnumerable<Layout> layouts;

    private const string LOG = "publish.log";

    public MultiSheetsPdfPlot(string pdfFile, IEnumerable<Layout> layouts)
    {
        Database db = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
        this.dwgFile = db.Filename;
        this.pdfFile = pdfFile;
        this.outputDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.pdfFile);
        this.dsdFile = Path.ChangeExtension(this.pdfFile, "dsd");
        this.layouts = layouts;
    }

    public void Publish()
    {
        if (TryCreateDSD())
        {
            Publisher publisher = AcAp.Publisher;
            PlotProgressDialog plotDlg = new PlotProgressDialog(false, this.sheetNum, true);
            publisher.PublishDsd(this.dsdFile, plotDlg);
            plotDlg.Destroy();
            File.Delete(this.dsdFile);
        }
    }

    private bool TryCreateDSD()
    {
        using (DsdData dsd = new DsdData())
        using (DsdEntryCollection dsdEntries = CreateDsdEntryCollection(this.layouts))
        {
            if (dsdEntries == null || dsdEntries.Count <= 0) return false;

            if (!Directory.Exists(this.outputDir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(this.outputDir);

            this.sheetNum = dsdEntries.Count;

            dsd.SetDsdEntryCollection(dsdEntries);

            dsd.SetUnrecognizedData("PwdProtectPublishedDWF", "FALSE");
            dsd.SetUnrecognizedData("PromptForPwd", "FALSE");
            dsd.SheetType = SheetType.MultiDwf;
            dsd.NoOfCopies = 1;
            dsd.DestinationName = this.pdfFile;
            dsd.IsHomogeneous = false;
            dsd.LogFilePath = Path.Combine(this.outputDir, LOG);

            PostProcessDSD(dsd);

            return true;
        }
    }

    private DsdEntryCollection CreateDsdEntryCollection(IEnumerable<Layout> layouts)
    {
        DsdEntryCollection entries = new DsdEntryCollection();

        foreach (Layout layout in layouts)
        {
            DsdEntry dsdEntry = new DsdEntry();
            dsdEntry.DwgName = this.dwgFile;
            dsdEntry.Layout = layout.LayoutName;
            dsdEntry.Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.dwgFile) + "-" + layout.LayoutName;
            dsdEntry.Nps = layout.TabOrder.ToString();
            entries.Add(dsdEntry);
        }
        return entries;
    }

    private void PostProcessDSD(DsdData dsd)
    {
        string str, newStr;
        string tmpFile = Path.Combine(this.outputDir, "temp.dsd");

        dsd.WriteDsd(tmpFile);

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tmpFile, Encoding.Default))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(this.dsdFile, false, Encoding.Default))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                str = reader.ReadLine();
                if (str.Contains("Has3DDWF"))
                {
                    newStr = "Has3DDWF=0";
                }
                else if (str.Contains("OriginalSheetPath"))
                {
                    newStr = "OriginalSheetPath=" + this.dwgFile;
                }
                else if (str.Contains("Type"))
                {
                    newStr = "Type=6";
                }
                else if (str.Contains("OUT"))
                {
                    newStr = "OUT=" + this.outputDir;
                }
                else if (str.Contains("IncludeLayer"))
                {
                    newStr = "IncludeLayer=TRUE";
                }
                else if (str.Contains("PromptForDwfName"))
                {
                    newStr = "PromptForDwfName=FALSE";
                }
                else if (str.Contains("LogFilePath"))
                {
                    newStr = "LogFilePath=" + Path.Combine(this.outputDir, LOG);
                }
                else
                {
                    newStr = str;
                }
                writer.WriteLine(newStr);
            }
        }
        File.Delete(tmpFile);
    }

    [CommandMethod("PlotPdf")]
    public void PlotPdf()
    {
        Database db = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
        short bgp = (short)Application.GetSystemVariable("BACKGROUNDPLOT");
        try
        {
            Application.SetSystemVariable("BACKGROUNDPLOT", 0);
            using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                List<Layout> layouts = new List<Layout>();
                DBDictionary layoutDict =
                    (DBDictionary)db.LayoutDictionaryId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                foreach (DBDictionaryEntry entry in layoutDict)
                {
                    if (entry.Key != "Model")
                    {
                        layouts.Add((Layout)tr.GetObject(entry.Value, OpenMode.ForRead));
                    }
                }
                layouts.Sort((l1, l2) => l1.TabOrder.CompareTo(l2.TabOrder));

                string filename = Path.ChangeExtension(db.Filename, "pdf");

                MultiSheetsPdf plotter = new MultiSheetsPdf(filename, layouts);
                plotter.Publish();

                tr.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
            ed.WriteMessage("\nError: {0}\n{1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            Application.SetSystemVariable("BACKGROUNDPLOT", bgp);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please show what *error* do you get ?

Comment: CS1520 Method must have a return type                                        CS1729 'MultiSheetsPdf' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Comment: Okay, since you intend to define a constructor there. Try changing your **public MultiSheetsPdfPlot(string pdfFile, IEnumerable<Layout> layouts)** to **public MultiSheetsPdf(string pdfFile, IEnumerable<Layout> layouts)**.

Comment: Actually i am new in here can you please edit my code according to the changes please.

Comment: Normally people don't like it when you ask them to modify your code for you. But since you're very new, see the answer below. You had error in your constructor definition. Atleast, now you should not get any compilation errors if your references and namespaces are correct.

Comment: It gives me exception "No parameterless constuctor defined in this object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: **(Try to note and *understand* the difference between your version and this version)**

```
    namespace Plottings
    {

    public class MultiSheetsPdf
    {
        private string dwgFile, pdfFile, dsdFile, outputDir;
        private int sheetNum;
        private IEnumerable<Layout> layouts;

        private const string LOG = "publish.log";
        public MultiSheetsPdf(){}
        public MultiSheetsPdf(string pdfFile, IEnumerable<Layout> layouts)
        {
            Database db = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
            this.dwgFile = db.Filename;
            this.pdfFile = pdfFile;
            this.outputDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.pdfFile);
            this.dsdFile = Path.ChangeExtension(this.pdfFile, "dsd");
            this.layouts = layouts;
        }

        public void Publish()
        {
            if (TryCreateDSD())
            {
                Publisher publisher = AcAp.Publisher;
                PlotProgressDialog plotDlg = new PlotProgressDialog(false, this.sheetNum, true);
                publisher.PublishDsd(this.dsdFile, plotDlg);
                plotDlg.Destroy();
                File.Delete(this.dsdFile);
            }
        }

        private bool TryCreateDSD()
        {
            using (DsdData dsd = new DsdData())
            using (DsdEntryCollection dsdEntries = CreateDsdEntryCollection(this.layouts))
            {
                if (dsdEntries == null || dsdEntries.Count <= 0) return false;

                if (!Directory.Exists(this.outputDir))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(this.outputDir);

                this.sheetNum = dsdEntries.Count;

                dsd.SetDsdEntryCollection(dsdEntries);

                dsd.SetUnrecognizedData("PwdProtectPublishedDWF", "FALSE");
                dsd.SetUnrecognizedData("PromptForPwd", "FALSE");
                dsd.SheetType = SheetType.MultiDwf;
                dsd.NoOfCopies = 1;
                dsd.DestinationName = this.pdfFile;
                dsd.IsHomogeneous = false;
                dsd.LogFilePath = Path.Combine(this.outputDir, LOG);

                PostProcessDSD(dsd);

                return true;
            }
        }

        private DsdEntryCollection CreateDsdEntryCollection(IEnumerable<Layout> layouts)
        {
            DsdEntryCollection entries = new DsdEntryCollection();

            foreach (Layout layout in layouts)
            {
                DsdEntry dsdEntry = new DsdEntry();
                dsdEntry.DwgName = this.dwgFile;
                dsdEntry.Layout = layout.LayoutName;
                dsdEntry.Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.dwgFile) + "-" + layout.LayoutName;
                dsdEntry.Nps = layout.TabOrder.ToString();
                entries.Add(dsdEntry);
            }
            return entries;
        }

        private void PostProcessDSD(DsdData dsd)
        {
            string str, newStr;
            string tmpFile = Path.Combine(this.outputDir, "temp.dsd");

            dsd.WriteDsd(tmpFile);

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tmpFile, Encoding.Default))
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(this.dsdFile, false, Encoding.Default))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    str = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (str.Contains("Has3DDWF"))
                    {
                        newStr = "Has3DDWF=0";
                    }
                    else if (str.Contains("OriginalSheetPath"))
                    {
                        newStr = "OriginalSheetPath=" + this.dwgFile;
                    }
                    else if (str.Contains("Type"))
                    {
                        newStr = "Type=6";
                    }
                    else if (str.Contains("OUT"))
                    {
                        newStr = "OUT=" + this.outputDir;
                    }
                    else if (str.Contains("IncludeLayer"))
                    {
                        newStr = "IncludeLayer=TRUE";
                    }
                    else if (str.Contains("PromptForDwfName"))
                    {
                        newStr = "PromptForDwfName=FALSE";
                    }
                    else if (str.Contains("LogFilePath"))
                    {
                        newStr = "LogFilePath=" + Path.Combine(this.outputDir, LOG);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newStr = str;
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine(newStr);
                }
            }
            File.Delete(tmpFile);
        }

        [CommandMethod("PlotPdf")]
        public void PlotPdf()
        {
            Database db = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
            short bgp = (short)Application.GetSystemVariable("BACKGROUNDPLOT");
            try
            {
                Application.SetSystemVariable("BACKGROUNDPLOT", 0);
                using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                {
                    List<Layout> layouts = new List<Layout>();
                    DBDictionary layoutDict =
                        (DBDictionary)db.LayoutDictionaryId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                    foreach (DBDictionaryEntry entry in layoutDict)
                    {
                        if (entry.Key != "Model")
                        {
                            layouts.Add((Layout)tr.GetObject(entry.Value, OpenMode.ForRead));
                        }
                    }
                    layouts.Sort((l1, l2) => l1.TabOrder.CompareTo(l2.TabOrder));

                    string filename = Path.ChangeExtension(db.Filename, "pdf");

                    MultiSheetsPdf plotter = new MultiSheetsPdf(filename, layouts);
                    plotter.Publish();

                    tr.Commit();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
                ed.WriteMessage("\nError: {0}\n{1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                Application.SetSystemVariable("BACKGROUNDPLOT", bgp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still give error at constructor "public MultiSheetsPdf(){}"as methos must have return type.

Comment: Sorry wrong placement. Moved that code just above the existing constructor. Now it should not have any constructor related errors.

Comment: Last thing i want to ask how can we change the location where to save the pdf file?

Comment: Here on this line: **string filename = Path.ChangeExtension(db.Filename, "pdf");** . So, set your **db.Filename** to where you want to save. Probably it is coming from database, so better change it there itself.

Comment: I wrote and publish the code of the upper MultiSheetsPdf class at TheSwamp:
https://www.theswamp.org/index.php?topic=31897.msg494504#msg494504
The 'CommandMethod' was not defined inside the MultiSheetsPdfand, IMO it has nothing to do here

Comment: And please, jackson Aj jags, aj_jags or whatever your avatar, stop double posting:
http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/the-code-is-giving-exception/m-p/6519328#U6519328

Answer (score 0):

Heads up.  The method, PostProcessDSD, tests are too generic.  Client contacted me complaining that one of his files was not plotting.  It was named "SOUTH".  The test for "OUT" in the string caused the issue.  No errors were thrown.  Just a good ol' fashion mystery.
Change all tests to include the "=".  ie else if (str.Contains("OUT=")) { ...